# Using openswan on raspian get "We cannot identify ourselves with either end of this network"

Tags: networking, vpn, raspbian, ipsec, l2tp

I just spent several hours fighting with Raspberry Pi 3 to get it to connect to my VPN at work.  I got OpenSwan installed and (apparently) configured, and also xl2ptd.  After starting the services and trying to bring up a connection, I kept getting the message `022 "MyConn": We cannot identify ourselves with either end of this connection.`

I had `left` in the configuration file set to `%defaultroute` and `right` sent to the proper public IP of the server.

How to get past this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case at least, the problem was that I had `protostack=auto` in the `config setup` section of `/etc/ipsec.conf`, which is how it came by default.  The corresponding comment in the default configuration file suggests this should work: "which IPsec stack to use. auto will try netkey, then klips then mast".

In fact, the problem was that `auto` apparently does not work as advertised.  I changed it explicitly to `protostack=netkey` and it worked.  Credit to [this thread](https://lists.openswan.org/pipermail/users/2016-January/023492.html) that did ultimately have this answer, although it took a long time to find it amongst the many configurations on the web and the apparently many causes for this error message.

I should also give a nod to [this post](http://sgros.blogspot.com/2013/08/getting-libreswan-connect-to-cisco-asa.html), which also addressed the same error.  The author there tracked it to the fact that NETKEY was not loading.  I followed his suggestions and executed the command `modprobe af_key`, which did, in the logs, appear to get me past the problem of not having NETKEY start.  As noted above, that wasn't sufficient for me though as I continued to get the same error after doing this as before.  I cannot, therefore, be certain if this was an additional necessary step or a red herring in my case.